# BigInteger Conversion from int to BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm having trouble working with BigIntegers. I'm having trouble with the `add` method in the Rational class. In the `Rational(int x, int y)` constructor I'm trying to convert the parameters datatype `int` into the instance variable datatype of `BigInteger` though the use of the`toString(int n)` method.

1. Am I doing the conversion correctly inside the `Rational(int x, int y)` constructor?
2. They way the `add` method is written I'm getting an error under all of n.num and n.den. I don't understand why I'm getting that error. Am I not correctly using the `add` method from the BigInteger class? 
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Suppose one class has the following

```
Rational a = new Rational(1,2);
Rational b = new Rational(1,3);
Rational c = new Rational(1,6);
Rational sum = a.add(b).add(c);
println(sum);
```

and the Rational class includes

```
import acm.program.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Rational{

    public Rational(int x, int y) {
        num = new BigInteger(toString(x));
        den = new BigInteger(toString(y));
    }

    public toString(int n) {
        return toString(n); 
    }

    public BigInteger add(BigInteger n) {
        return new BigInteger(this.num * n.den + n.num * this.den, this.den *  n.den)
    }

    /*  private instance variables  */
    private BigInteger num; 
    private BigInteger den;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert an int to BigInteger I would use `BigInteger.valueOf(int)`.

Also, you cannot use operators with BigIntegers, you must use its own methods. Your methos should be like this:

```
public Rational add(Rational n) {
    return new Rational(
             this.num.multiply(n.den).add(n.num.multiply(this.den)).intValue(),
             this.den.multiply(n.den).intValue());
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this.  If you're adding lots of Rationals together, the denominators can blow up exponentially.  For example, 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 will give you 500/625, instead of 4/5.  You really want to add a step to remove any common factors between the numerator and the denominator, before returning the new value.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm still confused on one thing. If you look at the BigInteger javadoc page, BigInteger has a `add` method. Can't you use that method in this case? If not, when can you use the BigInteger `add` method with this + val on the Javadoc page?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)

Comment: There is no + for `BigInteger` objects.  Use + to add two `int`s and `add()` to add two `BigInteger`s.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Am I doing the conversion correctly inside the Rational(int x, int
>   y) constructor?

You can use

```
BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
```

Making a String first is is not required.

```
2. They way the add method is written I'm getting an error .....
```

Your add method is wrong and its not clear what your are trying to acheive in your add method. But if your want to do addition in BigInteger you should use [BigInteger#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add%28java.math.BigInteger%29) method and for multiplication between BigInteger you should use [BigInteger#multiply](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply%28java.math.BigInteger%29) method.

Comment: I think I will use BigInteger.valueOf(x). But if you did choose to use toString, is toString used correctly?

Comment: No your toString method was wrong.... It should be `public toString(int n) {
    return toString(n); 
}`

Comment: You could get rid of your `toString` method and use the one in the `Integer` class - like `num = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(x));` if you wanted to.  But why not just use `BigInteger.valueOf(x)`?  It's much tidier.

Comment: @Jayamohan Is my toString(int n) method and your toString method answer two posts above this the same? Is the toString method written correctly? In this circumstance, does toString(int n) return `return (n)` or `return (int n)`?

Answer (score 2):

A simple error:

```
public Rational add(Rational n) {
    return new Rational(
        this.num.multiply(n.den).add(n.num.multiply(this.den)),
        this.den.multiply(n.den));
}
```

Also, when creating a new `BigInteger` you should use the `valueOf(int)` method instead of converting to `String`

Comment: @JimGerrison When I copy and paste your code into Eclispe there is a red error line under (this.num * n.den + n.num * this.den, this.den *  n.den). The error reads                                            - The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigInteger, 
  java.math.BigInteger
 - The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigInteger, 
  java.math.BigInteger

Comment: You would need to use the `multiply` and `add` methods of BigInteger... I've updated my answer.

Comment: @JessicaM -- use `BigInteger.multiply()`.. Java doesn't have operator overloading, Garrison wrote "mental logic" or essentially pseudo-code.  Java does not have operator overloading.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use + inside the add method. Aren't I using BigInteger add method? this + val?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)

Comment: No. As @ThomasW said, Java does not overload operators. You must explicitly invoke the `add` and `multiply` methods when working with `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the denominators blowing up exponentially, I would use the lowest common multiple of the two denominators as the denominator of the result, not their product.  This would look like this.

```
public Rational add(Rational rhs) {
    BigInteger commonFactor = den.gcd(rhs.den);
    BigInteger resultNumerator = 
        num.multiply(rhs.den).add(rhs.num.multiply(den)).divide(commonFactor);
    BigInteger resultDenominator = den.multiply(rhs.den).divide(commonFactor);

    return new Rational(resultNumerator, resultDenominator);
}
```

To use this exactly how I've written it, you'll need a new constructor that takes two `BigInteger` arguments; but you probably want that anyway.

Comment: It took me a little while to fully understand what you were trying to say but it this correct. You always want to reduce the two denominators you're working with at the moment in the program to their greatest common denominator when working with fractions and other type of rationals because there could potentially be a mess by multiplying the denominators instead of simply adding them?

Comment: Err, kind of.  It may be easiest to see with an example.  If I add 1/8 + 1/12, and I use the approach in trogdor's solution and Jim Garrison's solution, I finish up with (1 x 12 + 1 x 8)/(8 x 12), which is 20/96.  This is correct, but not in simplest form.  With my approach, you start by finding the GCD of 8 and 12 (which is 4), and dividing through as you go.  This gives 5/24, which is both correct and in simplest form.  The difference might not seem significant when you add two rational numbers, but as you add more and more numbers, the denominators end up increasing exponentially.  This ...

Comment: ... is a particular problem in trogdor's solution, which uses intValue on the numerator and denominator.  So it would fail, for example, to add 1/17 + 1/17 + 1/17 + 1/17 + 1/17 + 1/17 + 1/17 + 1/17.  Here, instead of giving 8/17 as an answer (which my solution would), trogdor's solution will give you an arithmetic overflow, because both the numerator and the denominator end up being too big to store in an int.